# Is there a pandas/numpy method to remove this nested for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find a solution that utilises the pandas and/or numpy libaries to do the below.
I am merging where the track is equal across dataframes, and the location in the merged_df falls between the start and end values of df3.

I'm sure there is a way using the pandas merge function, but I can't work out how to do it between a range.

```
df1_length = len(df1.axes[0])
df2_length = len(df2.axes[0])

for j in range(df1_length):
    for k in range(df2_length):
        if (df1.at[j, 'Track'] == df2.at[k, 'Track'] and
           df1.at[j, 'Location'] >= df2.at[k, 'Start'] and
           df1.at[j, 'Location'] <= df2.at[k, 'End']):
            df1.at[j, 'Label'] = df2.at[k, 'Label']
            if df2.at[k, 'Label'] == 'Curve':
                df1.at[j, 'Superelevation'] = df2.at[k, 'Superelevation']
                df1.at[j, 'Curve Radius'] = df2.at[k, 'Curve Radius']
            break
```

df1:

| Track | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Up | 1234 |
| Up | 2354 |
| Up | 4521 |
| Up | 8654 |
| Up | 9876 |

df2:

| Track | Start | End | Label | Superelevation | Curve Radius | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Up | 0 | 2000 | Curve | 60 | 3200 | R |
| Up | 3000 | 4600 | Transition |  |  |  |
| Up | 9500 | 10000 | Curve | 35 | 900 | L |
| Down | 0 | 9999 | Curve | 20 | 1700 | L |

output:

| Track | Location | Label | Superelevation | Curve Radius | Direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Up | 1234 | Curve | 60 | 3200 | R |
| Up | 2354 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Up | 4521 | Transition | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Up | 8654 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Up | 9876 | Curve | 35 | 900 | L |

Comment: Maybe you could do merge_asof() to find the nearest Start lower than Location, then filter out rows with an End which is smaller than Location? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Track')

df_merged['Label'] = np.where((df_merged['Location'] >= df_merged['Start']) & (df_merged['Location'] <= df_merged['End']), df_merged['Label'], np.nan)
df_merged['Superelevation'] = np.where((df_merged['Location'] >= df_merged['Start']) & (df_merged['Location'] <= df_merged['End']), df_merged['Superelevation'], np.nan)
df_merged['Curve Radius'] = np.where((df_merged['Location'] >= df_merged['Start']) & (df_merged['Location'] <= df_merged['End']), df_merged['Curve Radius'], np.nan)
df_merged['Direction'] = np.where((df_merged['Location'] >= df_merged['Start']) & (df_merged['Location'] <= df_merged['End']), df_merged['Direction'], np.nan)

df_filtered = df_merged.dropna(subset='Label')

df_final = pd.merge(df_filtered, df1, on=['Location', 'Track'], how='right')
df_final.drop(labels=['Start', 'End'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `merge()` to inner join `merged_df` and `df3` on the `Track` columns and then do filtering.

```
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df3, on='Track', how='inner')
merged_df = merged.loc[(merged['Location'] >= merged['Start']) & (merged['Location'] <= merged['End'])].reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['Start', 'End'])
```

output:

```
>       Track  Location  Label  Superelevation  Curve Radius Direction
>     0    Up      1234  Curve              60          3200         R
>     1    Up      9876   Tang
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. this method does work, but I realised I made a mistake on my post.

df3 doesn't contain the 'tang' line, but once I have filtered, I wish to keep those lines. I tried merging on left but that doesn't work after filtering,